# Mysql Multiple queries on single php page to sum individual tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Lets say I want to execute 3 different sums on 3 different tables

```
SELECT sum(`diepoints`)  as exp FROM `dies` where user='coder'
SELECT sum(`winpoints`)  as rev FROM `wins` where user='coder'
SELECT sum(`debtpoints`) as deb FROM `debts` where user='coder'
```

I would like to  Execute those queries  in one statement .

```
$resource1= $con->query(SELECT sum(`diepoints`)  as exp FROM `dies` where user='coder');
$resource2 = $con->query(SELECT sum(`winpoints`)  as rev FROM `wins` where user='coder');
$resource3 = $con->query(SELECT sum(`debtpoints`) as deb FROM `debts` where user='coder');
```

and out put them like as per below.

```
Echo "Your total die points are".$row['exp'];
Echo "Your total die points are".$row['rev'];
Echo "Your total die points are".$row['deb'];
```

Any help explanation on how to combine this queries would be great .

Comment: If an answer below has solved your problem, please award one of them the green tick -- this will inform future readers that your question is resolved.  Please practice good SO citizenship.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT sum(`diepoints`)  as exp FROM `dies` where user='coder') as exp,
       (SELECT sum(`winpoints`)  as rev FROM `wins` where user='coder') as rev,
       (SELECT sum(`debtpoints`) as deb FROM `debts` where user='coder') as deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Select them all in a single row using subqueries like this:

```
select
(SELECT sum(`diepoints`)  as exp FROM `dies` where user='coder') exp,
(SELECT sum(`winpoints`)  as rev FROM `wins` where user='coder') rev,
(SELECT sum(`debtpoints`) as deb FROM `debts` where user='coder') deb
```